# Benchmarking CPU-bound algorithms/implementations

Tags: performance, benchmarking, cpu

Let's say I'm writing my own `StringBuilder` in a compiled language (e.g. C++).

What is the best way to measure the performance of various implementations? Simply timing a few hundred thousand runs yields highly inconsistent results: the timings from one batch to the other can differ by as much as 15%, making it impossible to accurately assess potential performance improvements that yield performance gains smaller than that.

I've done the following:

1. Disable SpeedStep
2. Use RDTSC for timing
3. Run the process with realtime priority
4. Set the affinity to a single CPU core

This stabilizied the results somewhat. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try timing more than a few hundred thousand runs. Run your benchmarks for at least 10 seconds each.

Comment: Indeed, that would be my fall-back plan. It does break the flow somewhat :)

Comment: From my experience, timing anything less than 1 second gives very inconsistent results even with hardware and performance counters.

Comment: Yep. My benchmarks run for at least 5 seconds. I'm going to increase the wordload 5x for now.

Comment: If you're seeing inconsistencies even at 10+ seconds, then there must be something wrong with the benchmark. There are many factors that could cause weird behavior. (alignment, cache state, etc...)

Comment: You seem to be doing all the right things. One thing which does not provide an answer to your question, but I have found useful, is to always run the test for a fixed amount of time and count how many operations you managed to do within that time interval, instead of running a fixed number of operations and counting the time they took.

Comment: Mike, why would that be better? Did you simply get more consistent results that way?

Comment: No, I did not, that's why I said that it does not provide an answer to your question. All that it does is guarantee to me the time that the test will run, so I know whether I have time to go make some coffee, watch the next episode of The Big Bang Theory, etc.

Comment: You could also use cycles if you are benchmarking on the same hardware. Then it would be speed independent.

Comment: Newer CPUs have a "constant rate TSC", which means that the counter returned by `rdtsc` closer approximates the elapsed time, rather than cycle count. I'm not sure if disabling SpeedStep on Core i7 is enough to counter this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to precisely measure a piece of code. For such requirements, I recommend you to have look at [Agner Fog's test suite](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp). By using it, you can measure clock cycles and collect some important factors (such as cache misses, branch mispredictions etc.).

Also, I recommend you to have look at [PDF document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) from Agner's site. It's a really invaluable document to make possible such micro-optimization.

As a side note, actual performance is not a function of "clock cycles". Cache misses can change everything for each run within a real application. So, I would optimize cache misses first. Simply running a piece of code several times for same memory portion, decreases cache miss dramatically. So, it makes it hard to measure precisely. Whole application tuning is usually better idea IMO. Intel VTune and other tools are really good for such usages.

Comment: I believe all emulators simulate highly deterministic in-order CPU. So, they don't even reflect actual performance by using RDTSC in them. I believe authors assigned some fixed clock cycles for each instruction and counts them. So, this is much likely counting some ad-hoc fixed numbers which are unrelated to actual performance. Note that, today CPU's have several pipelines. And performance function is somewhat more complex.

Comment: It's indisputable that clock counts - whether on real or emulated CPUs - do not indicate actual performance, however their potential to be highly consistent across runs does make them useful in their own way.

Comment: I agree. But, counting some ad-hoc numbers which are determined by emulators' authors do not reflect anything either. As to consistency, it's no wonder because they are just some deterministic numbers inside a emulator. I think, Agnor's test suit is really what you want.

Comment: Agner Fog's PMCTest seems to yield very consistent results. For example, the `Instruct` counter has an error under 0.01%. Messing around with Bochs was fun, but I probably should have tried this sooner :)

Comment: I've told you that it's really what you want ;)

Answer (score 7):

I have achieved 100% consistent results in this manner:

1. Set up Bochs with MS-DOS.
2. Set up your toolchain to target MS-DOS
   — or —

   1. Set up your toolchain to target 32-bit Windows
   2. Install the [HX-DOS extender](http://www.japheth.de/HX.html) in Bochs.
   3. If necessary, hack your toolkit's standard library / runtime and stub out/remove features requiring Windows APIs not implemented in HX-DOS. The extender will print a list of unimplemented APIs when you attempt to run the program.
3. Reduce the number of cycles in your benchmark by a few orders of magnitude.
4. Wrap the benchmark code with assembler `cli` / `sti` instructions (note that the binary won't run on modern OSes after this change).
5. If you haven't already, make your benchmark use `rdtsc` deltas for timing. The samples should be within the `cli`…`sti` instructions.
6. Run it in the Bochs!

[image: Bochs screenshot]

The result seems to be completely deterministic, but is not an accurate assessment of overall performance (see the discussion under Osman Turan's answer for details).

---

As a bonus tip, here's an easy way to share files with Bochs (so you don't have to unmount/rebuild/remount the floppy image every time):

On Windows, Bochs will lock the floppy image file, but the file is still opened in shared-write mode. This means that you can't overwrite the file, but you can write to it. (I think *nix OSes might cause overwriting to create a new file, as far as file descriptors are concerned.) The trick is to use [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29). I had the following batch script set up:

```
... benchmark build commands here ...
copy /Y C:\Path\To\Benchmark\Project\test2dos.exe floppy\test2.exe
bfi -t=288 -f=floppysrc.img floppy
dd if=floppysrc.img of=floppy.img
```

`bfi` is Bart's [Build Floppy Image](http://www.nu2.nu/bfi/).

Then, just mount `floppy.img` in Bochs.

---

Bonus tip #2: To avoid having to manually start the benchmark every time in Bochs, put an empty `go.txt` file in the floppy directory, and run this batch in Bochs:

```
@echo off
A:
:loop
choice /T:y,1 > nul
if not exist go.txt goto loop
del go.txt
echo ---------------------------------------------------
test2
goto loop
```

It will start the test program every time it detects a fresh floppy image. This way, you can automate a benchmark run in a single script.

---

Update: this method is not very reliable. Sometimes the timings would change as much as by 200% just by reordering some tests (these timing changes were not observed when ran on real hardware, using the methods described in the original question).

Comment: Cool!  C-:=  It is a pity that one has to use an entire virtual machine for this job, since an interpreter of a single piece of self-contained 386 code should suffice for benchmarking. If only it was possible to find such a thing!

Comment: Why do you suggest using MS-DOS? You may want to set clock: sync=slowdown in your [bochs.rc](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/bochsrc.html).

Comment: Well, because MS-DOS has very little overhead and does not have preemptive multitasking.

Answer (score 1):

I have been concerned about this issue a lot in the past, and I have come to the realization that there is only one <strike>perfect</strike> ideal solution, which though requires a lot of work, (preparation mostly,) so I never actually did it this way.

The solution is to run your code using a 386 emulator which will tell you exactly how many operations were executed. You should be able to find an open-source 386 emulator out there. It will be accurate to the instruction, and it will require a single run of your test.  If you do it, please post how you did it!

Comment: Haha, I was setting up BOCHS as you posted this :) Indeed, BOCHS' `rdtsc` instruction returns a virtual counter, so I think it'll be much more accurate.

Comment: I did it! See my answer below.